# How to remove duplicate event?

Tags: javascript, jsp

My some jsp Program  self submit for data save.

I have to Continuously Save action occure memory leak..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlSeb.png)

How to  forced remove duplicate event script in javascript??

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in debounce:

Using Lodash:

```
_.debounce(func, [wait=0], [options={}])
```

Vanilla JS implementation:

```
let debounce = > (func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;

  return function executedFunction() {
    var context = this;
    var args = arguments;

    var later = function() {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };

    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;

    clearTimeout(timeout);

    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
};

// to call this
debounce(function() {
  // All the taxing stuff you do
}, 250);
```